# All users' password automatically changed in database time to time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter php framework. I am suffering from the problem that all the userss password automatically get changes in database sometime, please help.

This is my reset code

```
    function reset_now($key){
        //key of fourth segment is saved on cookie

$key = $this->uri->segment(4);



        //start validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','xss_clean|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|matches[password_conf]|sha1');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_conf','Password Confirmation','xss_clean|required|alpha_numeric|matches[password]|sha1');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){


            $this->load->view('account/reset_password');


        }else{


            $this->db->set('password', $this->_salt.$this->input->post('password'));
                    $this->db->where('lostkey', $_POST['lostkey']);
            $this->db->update('users');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Password changed, please login with new password');



                    redirect('account/login');
        //$this->load->view('account/reset_password_complete');
    }

}
```

Comment: Without any code this is going to be a hard problem to solve. Is there anyway you could review your applications code and post the relevant parts? I'm sure that a framework as well renowned as CI would be free of serious errors like this.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question, are you using any plugins for database, or can you share some code references you have (like your controller/Modal, database.php from config) so that we can help you. what database you are using, which version of codeigniter you are using. also which encryption you use for password. is there any plugin you use or some custom code to encrypt your passwords. Because there are many possibilities and I am 100% sure that there is no as such flaws/bugs in Codeigniter framework.

Comment: Code doesn't run by itself, nor writes itself. CI is no Skynet, you must be doing something wrong somewhere in your code, maybe a wrong update statement. With this level of information, this question can't be answered, please add more details and relevant code

Comment: Password reset function is updated i think it's causing problem when somebody change pass everybody get changed, pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have forgot where condition in password update sql. Please re-check your sql. Passwords will not get changed automatically. It might be trigged when someone tries to change password.

---

UPDATE as per the code provided

Your update where condition is,
`$this->db->where('lostkey', $_POST['lostkey']);`

The `where` clause should use the user id(the primary key of the user in database) instead using `lostkey`( i dont what it means, it is possible that there are multiple rows with same `lostkey`).

So, your `where` clause must be something like

`$this->db->where('id', $user_id)`.

Comment: you are right , please help to to correct i have updated code in original post

Comment: @sagarmatha woudl you mind accepting the answer, if this solved your problem

Comment: Thanks i accepted it but i would love to see full  example code